# Diagonalisable representation over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm looking for a real representation of an abelian group which is not 1 dimensional. I've constructed the following representation of $C_3 = \left<x \mid x^3=1\right>$; $\rho: C_3 \to GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ by:

$$x \mapsto 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos(2\pi/3) & \sin(2\pi/3)  \\
-\sin(2\pi/3) & \cos(2\pi/3)  \end{array} \right) $$

which corresponds to rotating by $120^{\circ}$.

The question I am asking is, in order to show this representation is irreducible, does it suffice to show that this matrix cannot be diagonalised over $\mathbb{R}$? And if so, does it then suffice to show it has no real eigenvalues, let alone two l.i. eigenvectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In order to show this representation is irreducible, does it suffice to show that this matrix cannot be diagonalised over $\mathbb{R}$?"

Yes. By Masche's theorem, the representation is irreducible if and only if it is indecomposable. Since this representation is two-dimensional, a direct sum decomposition of $\rho$ would give a decomposition of $\mathbb R^2$ into one-dimensional invariant subspaces for $\rho(x)$, i.e., a diagonalization of $\rho(x)$.

"And if so, does it then suffice to show it has no real eigenvalues, let alone two l.i. eigenvectors?"

Yes. An eigenvalue for $\rho(x)$ would give an eigenvector for $\rho(x)$, which would span a proper subrepresentation of $\rho$. (No need to allude to Masche's theorem for this line of reasoning.)